# Invalidating an ImageView after an onClick()

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I have an onClick() method within an activity, and that onClick() method changes the photo for an ImageView. I want to invalidate the ImageView and re-draw it after the onClick(), however neither imageView.invalidate() nor imageView.postInvalidate() nor view.invalidate() nor view.postInvalidate() is causing the ImageView to refresh. Instead, it refreshes the next time it is clicked. Here is the method:

```
public void onImageViewProfileClick(View view) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    // Use this to restrict items to those on the SD card:
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    if (image != null) {
        imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(image);
        view.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Here is the complete method:

```
package com.example.news_app.android.ui;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.example.news_app.android.DataManager;
import com.example.news_app.R;
import com.example.news_app.android.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    private Settings appSettings = new Settings(this);
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAbout;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPhone;
    private ImageView imageViewProfile;
    private Bitmap image = null;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    // The image will be scaled to 32x32
    public static final int IMAGE_SIZE = 32;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        editTextAbout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAbout);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        imageViewProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile);
        editTextName.setText(appSettings.getName());
        editTextAbout.setText(appSettings.getAbout());
        editTextEmail.setText(appSettings.getEmail());
        editTextPhone.setText(appSettings.getPhone());
        Bitmap profile = appSettings.getProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(profile);
        }
        if (appSettings.getName().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "You have to enter a name before you can post or comment",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onImageViewProfileClick(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        // Use this to restrict items to those on the SD card:
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
        if (image != null) {
            imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(image);
            view.postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "FileNotFoundException");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap unscaledImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,
                    null, null);
            image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(unscaledImage, IMAGE_SIZE,
                    IMAGE_SIZE);
            Log.d("Unscaled image byte count",
                    "Bytes: " + unscaledImage.getByteCount());
            Log.d("Scaled image byte count", "Bytes: " + image.getByteCount());
        }
    }

    public void onButtonSaveClick(View view) {
        String editTextNameInput = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String editTextAboutInput = editTextAbout.getText().toString();
        String editTextEmailInput = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String editTextPhoneInput = editTextPhone.getText().toString();
        Bitmap imageViewProfileInput = ((BitmapDrawable) imageViewProfile
                .getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        if (editTextNameInput != null) {
            appSettings.setName(editTextNameInput);
        }
        if (editTextAboutInput != null) {
            appSettings.setAbout(editTextAboutInput);
        }
        if (editTextEmailInput != null) {
            appSettings.setEmail(editTextEmailInput);
        }
        if (editTextPhoneInput != null) {
            appSettings.setPhone(editTextPhoneInput);
        }
        if (imageViewProfileInput != null) {
            appSettings.setProfile(imageViewProfileInput);
        }
        DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(this);
        dataManager.addUser(appSettings.getUserId(), appSettings.getName(),
                appSettings.getAbout(), appSettings.getEmail(),
                appSettings.getPhone());
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the invalidation into the onActivityResult() method. I added the invalidation after here:

```
        image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(unscaledImage, IMAGE_SIZE,
                IMAGE_SIZE);
        imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(image);
        imageViewProfile.postInvalidate();
```